# Big O Complexity of a method

Tags: performance, big-o

I have this method:

```
public static int what(String str, char start, char end)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) == start)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<str.length(); j++)
            {
                if(str.charAt(j) == end)
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

What I need to find is:

1) What is it doing? Answer: counting the total number of *end* occurrences after **EACH** (or is it? Not specified in the assignment, point 3 depends on this) *start*.

2) What is its complexity? Answer: the first loops iterates over the string completely, so it's at least *O(n)*, the second loop executes only if *start* char is found and even then partially (index at which *start* was found + 1). Although, big O is all about worst case no? So in the worst case, *start* is the 1st char & the inner iteration iterates over the string n-1 times, the -1 is a constant so it's *n*. But, the inner loop won't be executed every outer iteration pass, statistically, but since big O is about worst case, **is it correct to say the complexity of it is O(n^2)**? Ignoring any constants and the fact that in 99.99% of times the inner loop won't execute every outer loop pass.

3) Rewrite it so that complexity is lower.
What I'm not sure of is whether ***start* occurs at most once** or more, if once at most, then method can be rewritten using one loop (having a flag indicating whether *start* has been encountered and from there on incrementing *count* at each *end* occurrence), yielding a complexity of **O(n)**.

In case though, that *start* can appear multiple times, which **most likely it is**, because assignment is of a Java course and I don't think they would make such ambiguity.
Solving, in this case, is not possible using one loop... **WAIT**! Yes it is..!
Just have a variable, say, *inc* to be incremented each time *start* is encountered & used to increment *count* each time *end* is encountered after the 1st *start* was found:

```
inc = 0, count = 0
if (current char == start) inc++
if (inc > 0 && current char == end) count += inc
```

This would also yield a complexity of **O(n)**? Because there is only 1 loop.

Yes I realize I wrote a lot hehe, but what I also realized is that I understand a lot better by forming my thoughts into words...

Comment: You really should break this up into a couple of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It increments `count` for every end character after any given start.  So if there's more than one start, it can increment it more than once for the same end.

   In the worst case, it will call charAt (n^2 - n) / 2 = ((n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1) times.  That is O(n^2).  This occurs when every character is start.

   If you were counting end characters after the first start, you could simply return count after the inner for.  But since the number of times count is incremented depends on the number of starts, your final psuedo-code is on the right track.  However, you need to switch the order of the ifs to deal with the special case where start == end.  You also don't need to check if inc > 0.

```
inc = 0, count = 0

if (current char == end) count += inc
if (current char == start) inc++
```

This is O(n) in all cases.

Comment: Actually, I think you need to look ahead one position for the end character as in the original it doesn't increment the count for the start character when start == end.  Consider the case when the string is "s" and start = "s" and end = "s".  If you don't look ahead, your get a count of 1 - you erroneously count the start character because it is the same as the end character.

Comment: Good point.  That can be fixed by switching the order of the ifs.

Comment: As I understood it, you begin counting occurrences of end only after the 1st start has been spotted, and then incrementing the amount added to count for every other start, or am I wrong? This is the reason I put the check inc > 0, because if inc is 0, that means no start has been spotted yet.

Comment: @time, yes, but if inc is 0, there is no harm in adding it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes.
2) Yes, the complexity is at best O(n) and at worst O(n^2).
3) Almost right. You need to check for the end character before the start character, otherwise the result is not always correct. Example in C#:

```
public static int what(string str, char start, char end) {
  int count = 0, mul = 0;
  foreach (char c in str) {
    if (c == end) count += mul;
    if (c == start) mul++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- As already pointed out by Matthew, the complexity of original method is O(*n<sup>2</sup>*)
- Your second approach is not correct, original method seems to be counting all substrings starting with *start* and ending with *end*, which can also **can contain** either *start* or *end*.
- It is possible to do this in O(*n*), just find all starts, all ends, and then iterate over two lists moving pointers appropriately.